# Preventing Site from Being Indexed by Search Engines

Tags: html, search-engine

How can I prevent Google and other search engines from indexing my website?

Comment: robots.txt directives in your /

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a `robots.txt` file in your site root with the following content:

```
# robots.txt for yoursite

User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Search engines (and **most** robots in general) will respect the contents of this file. You can put any number of `Disallow: /path` lines for robots to ignore. More details at [robotstxt.org](http://www.robotstxt.org/).

Comment: This guy says you should do something else, may be interesting : http://yoast.com/prevent-site-being-indexed/

Comment: Yes. This answer should be updated with the better one about the metatag

Comment: There is a difference between getting indexed and getting ranked.  The meta tag <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow"/> tells crawlers not to rank your site.  If you use the robots.txt, they will never see this and may still rank and list your site.

Answer (score 11):

I realize this is a very old question, but I wanted to highlight the comment made by @Julien as an actual answer.

[According to Joost de Valk](http://yoast.com/prevent-site-being-indexed/), robots.txt will indeed prevent your site from being crawled by search engines, but links to your site may still appear in search results if other sites have links that point to your site.

The solution is either adding a robots meta tag to the header of your pages:

`<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow"/>`

Or, a simpler option is to add the following to your .htaccess file:

`Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"`

Obviously your web host has to allow .htaccess rules and have the `mod_headers` module installed for that to work.

Both of these tags keep search engines from following links that point to your site AND displaying your pages in search results. Win-Win, baby.